# Exercise 39 from LPTHW trouble understanding loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working through Learning Python The Hard Way and I am having some trouble understanding, and finding information on, a certain loop in the exercise.

Here is the code.

```
statesAbbrev = {
"Oregon" : "OR",
"Florida" : "FL",
"California" : "CA",
"New York" : "NY",
"Michigan" : "MI",
"Washington" : "WA"
}

statesCities = {
"CA" : "San Francisco",
"MI" : "Detroit",
"FL" : "Jacksonville",
"WA" : "Seattle",
"NY" : "Buffalo"
}

print "-" * 10
for state, abbrev in statesAbbrev.items():  
    print "%s is abbreviated %s" % (state, abbrev)
```

I don't understand this for loop at all. I'm looking at it and its making my brain melt. I understand that statesAbbrev.items() is probably grabbing the first item from that dict, but 'state' hasn't been defined, and 'abbrev' is what? Also how can a for loop call on 'something, somethingElse'

Please help me understand!

You can find the whole exercise and all of the code here: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex39.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to Python programming!

`state` and `abbrev` are being defined *by* the for loop. `statesAbbrev.items()` returns a list of *tuples* that comprise the dictionary's keys and values:

```
[('Oregon', 'OR'), ('Florida', 'FL') ...]
```

So effectively you're looping through that list.

What

```
for state, abbrev in ...:
```

does is called *tuple unpacking*: taking a tuple of N elements and assigning it to N variables at once. So each time through the loop, `state` and `abbrev` are set to one of the entries in the `statesAbbrev` dictionary.

Hope that helps!

### EDIT: More fun with tuple unpacking

You can try tuple unpacking out for yourself, with as many values as you want:

```
In [1]: a,b,c = 1,2,3

In [2]: a
Out[2]: 1

In [3]: b
Out[3]: 2

In [4]: c
Out[4]: 3

In [5]: def x(): return (1,2,3,4)

In [6]: d,e,f,g = x()

In [7]: d
Out[7]: 1

In [8]: e
Out[8]: 2

In [9]: f
Out[9]: 3

In [10]: g
Out[10]: 4
```

But if you give it too few values, or too many, you get an error like this:

```
In [11]: a,b = (1,2,3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-9c07109388c5> in <module>()
----> 1 a,b = (1,2,3)

ValueError: too many values to unpack

In [12]: a,b,c,d,e,f,g = (1,2,3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-fcc71a498285> in <module>()
----> 1 a,b,c,d,e,f,g = (1,2,3)

ValueError: need more than 3 values to unpack
```

And as for loops:

```
In [13]: lst = [(1,2,3,4),(5,6,7,8)]

In [14]: for a,b,c,d in lst:
   ....:     print a,b,c,d
   ....:
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

[image: mind. blown.]

Comment: Whoa my mind is blown that is insane. Are there dictionaries and loops that can unpack triplets, then?

Comment: Correct, but just noting that since he is on python2 `statesAbbrev.items()` does return the list not the iterator, you have `statesAbbrev.iteritems()` for that.

Comment: @HarrisonBoles Updated with lots more examples

Comment: A great hidden feature of tuple unpacking: `start, *middle, end = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. `start` is `1`, `middle` is `[2, 3, 4]` and `end` is `5`.

Answer (score 2):

if you do:

```
print statesAbbrev.items()
```

you get the output:

```
[('Washington', 'WA'), ('Michigan', 'MI'), ('Florida', 'FL'), ('Oregon', 'OR'), ('New York', 'NY'), ('California', 'CA')]
```

which is a list of tuples, where each tuple has the key of the dictionary `statesAbbrev` as the first item in itself and the value of that key as the second item.

Now the loop in question should make sense!
:)